# Jquery form submission via radio button change

Tags: php, jquery, forms, radio-button

I've got a news managing script for my website that allows me to add, update, and delete news. I've decided to take on jQuery to make things smoother and, while I've got the add/edit/delete part working, there's a simple function I want to add on the default page for news editing.

When you visit the default news page, you're presented with a simple list of previous news posts. The columns displayed are:

News Title, Author, Release Date, Active, Edit

For the "Active" column I want a simple switch to set to either "Active" or "Inactive." Once that switch is flipped, that respective news post is updated without reloading the entire page. It just executes.

(Side note for UI: I also want to animate the cell color of the table of that news post, but that'll be something I can tackle later)

Currently the news-list.php script loads each row like so:

```
$news_edit_options .= "<tr id=\"" . $row["newsid"] . "\">";
$news_edit_options .= "     <td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>";
$news_edit_options .= "     <td>" . $row["login"] . "</td>";
$news_edit_options .= "     <td>" .$row["date_released"] . "</td>";
$news_edit_options .= "     <td>";
$news_edit_options .= "       <form method=\"post\" action=\"news-activator.php\" class=\"news-activator\">";
$news_edit_options .= "          <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"newsid\" value=\"" . $row["newsid"] . "\">";
$news_edit_options .= "          <input type=\"radio\" name=\"active\" value=\"0\"";
if ($row["active"] == 0) {
     $news_edit_options .= " checked";
}
$news_edit_options .= "> inactive <br />";

$news_edit_options .= " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"active\" value=\"1\"";
if ($row["active"] == 1) {
     $news_edit_options .= " checked";
}
$news_edit_options .= "> active";
$news_edit_options .= "  </form>";
$news_edit_options .= "</td>";
$news_edit_options .= "     <td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary newsbutton\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#newsModal\" id=\"" . $row["newsid"] . "\">Edit</button></td>";
$news_edit_options .= "</tr>";
```

That's working fine. Now onto the jQuery:

```
$.when(LoadAPage('#news-list','news-list.php')).done(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit(function() {
        // do stuff here
        });
    });
});
```

This just doesn't work. The `.submit(function() {});` portion flat out doesn't work. However, when I change it to:

```
$.when(LoadAPage('#news-list','news-list.php')).done(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

That'll "work," but the form just submits and I can't catch the data with jQuery and do all the things I want to do. I did try checkboxes but ran into the same problem.

I have a feeling that I'm just missing something or approaching this all wrong. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think you were half way there on both of your attempts, you just need to combine them together :)

```
$.when(LoadAPage('#news-list','news-list.php')).done(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("the form was submitted");
        });
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

The first submit function tells jQuery what to do when the form is submitted. The `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default action (which is submitting the form and reloading the page before you have time to do any other jQuery).

The second `.submit();` triggers a form submit which runs the code from our submit handler function.